# Mysql Relational Database Categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables I'm trying to make a input where users can search for a category for example pizza the database will find all restaurants within that category. My initial thoughts are to make the id of the category field in the table categories the primary key matching it to the restaurant table category field. However the problem I ran into is that only limits a restaurant to one. What would be the best configuration for what I'm asking.

Restaurants Table

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idRestaurant | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name         | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Password     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Email        | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Number       | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Categories Table

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idCategories | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Category     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Better u create another table.. that contain detail about what are all the catagories in currently having in that restaurant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a junction table as `restaurant_categories` which will maintain the relation for a restaurant to have more than one category

restaurant_categories

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| idCategories | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| idRestaurant | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This way you can assign multiple categories to a restaurant and for search you can use simple joins among your tables

```
select distinct r.* from Restaurants  r
join restaurant_categories rc on(r.idRestaurant = rc.idRestaurant )
join Categories c on (c.idCategories =rc.idCategories )
where c.Category ='pizza'
```

Comment: why do you have an extra id field

Comment: @user2872510 it denotes strong relations ship but if you don't need then just remove it ,its only for example

Comment: so are the idCategory and idRestaurant the primary keys and the foreign keys?

Comment: In `restaurant_categories(idRestaurant ,idCategories)` are foreign keys and `idRestaurant ,idCategories` in their own table behave as a primary key

Comment: when i run the join command i get Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'Restaurants'

Comment: @user2872510 this is a new question you should ask new one and if you want me to answer that post back the link here,also please post full details regarding your problem and the query or sample code you tried

Answer (score 1):

You need another table to store the relationships between Restaurants and Categories. This new table should have two fields:

```
Restuarant_id, category_id
```

This way you can store a row for every category belonging to a restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

Having a foreign ID key of one table (`restaurants.category_id`) corresponding to a primary field of another (`categories.id`) is the usual way of implementing a 1:N relationship. In this case, you would say that "restaurant belongs to a category" or that "category has many restaurants" (you can hear these terms very often from Rails developers).

If you wish to be able to assign multiple categories to restaurants, and multiple restaurants to a category, it is a N:N relationship ("has and belongs to many"), for which you need a third table, commonly known as a join table or a relationship table. In the original tables you'd just have their respective primary IDs; the new table would have two foreign keys to pair up restaurants with categories (`restaurant_categories.restaurant_id` and `restaurant_categories.category_id`).

Answer (score 1):

[How to define relationships between tables in an Access database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304466)

Read this. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a field categoryId in your table 'Restaurants' ?

You will be able to do requests like that :

```
SELECT idRestaurant FROM RestaurantTable WHERE categoryId = 1
```

With this structure, if you want to make a research by category you can do that :

```
SELECT r.Name FROM categories as c 
LEFT JOIN restaurants as r ON r.categoryId = c.idCategories 
WHERE c.Category LIKE '%Pizza%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a third table say `RestaurantsCategories`

```
+--------------+-------------+------+------------------------                               
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+------------------------                              
| idRestCat    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| idRestaurant | int(11)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| idCategories | int(11)     | NO   |     |         |       |      
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```